# IMU to Camera transformation

Tags: slam, imu, computer-vision, vio

Suppose you are implementing SLAM or VIO system, you have your camera C and IMU and a coordinate transformation between them (R, T).

How do convert IMU measurements to camera accelerations and rotations? Or vice versa? The papers I have read all assume the IMU is located at the focal point of the camera which is obviously not true.

Comment: See also: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/12512/coordinate-transform-of-accelerometer-on-rigid-body

Comment: That link from what I understand only gives linear accelerations and not angular velocity.